# What is the pattern for handling clean() when clean_fields() fails in Django Forms, Models and ModelForms?

Tags: python, django, validation, django-models, django-forms

In Django during `full_clean` of a `Form`, `ModelForm` or `Models`, first `clean_fields` is called and then `clean` is called even if `clean_fields` fails. This is a problem when I expect fields to pass `clean_fields` when computing `clean`. Consider the following example.

```
class SomeModel(Model):
  sum = models.SmallIntegerField()
  count = models.SmallIntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1)])

  def clean(self):
    if self.sum / self.count > 1:
      raise ValidationError('The average must not exceed 1.')
```

In the example above, `clean` with `sum=0`, `count=0` will yield `ZeroDivisionError`. Therefore, `full_clean` will yield `ZeroDivisionError` instead of actual error coming from `clean_fields`. Interestingly, clean will be called even if `sum='X'` or `sum=None`, i.e., is not even of correct type.

This means that `clean` cannot even depend on the fields being of correct type, much less passing some additional validation. How can I handle validation in a clean way without essentially running `clean_fields` (or doing it myself) from each `clean` I write?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the parent class clean method:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()

    if self.cleaned_data.get("sum") / self.cleaned_data.get("count") > 1:
      raise ValidationError('The average must not exceed 1.')

    return cleaned_data
```

Comment: This is true for forms and it still does not fix the problem, as `Form.clean` is defined as simply `return self.cleaned_data` and `Form.full_clean` calls both `clean_<field>` and `clean` even if the first one yields an error.